# Swift - declare 2d array contains

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array, contains, arc4random

I want to say that if some 2d array contains the "point" format [Int,Int], then regenerate the random numbers, not counting the iteration.

```
for _ in 0..<33{
        let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
        let k = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
        while live.contains(//The point j,k){
        live.append(Array(arrayLiteral: j,k))
            cells[j][k] = true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood your question, you want to generate an array of 2D points excluding repetition, you can use `CGPoint` or define your own `Point`

```
struct Point: Equatable {
    let x: Int
    let y: Int
}

func == (lhs: Point, rhs: Point) -> Bool {
    return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y
}

var live: [Point] = []
for _ in 0..<10{

    var candidate = Point(x: Int(arc4random_uniform(10)), y: Int(arc4random_uniform(10)))
    while live.contains(candidate) {
        candidate = Point(x: Int(arc4random_uniform(10)), y: Int(arc4random_uniform(10)))
    }
    live.append(candidate)
}
```

or you can use tuple like so

```
var live: [(Int, Int)] = []
for _ in 0..<10{
    var j = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
    var k = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
    while live.contains({$0 == (j, k)}) {
        j = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
        k = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
    }
    live.append((j,k))
}
```

Depending on your problem size, it might be more optimal to build an array of all possible values, and then shuffle and take first `X` elements every time you need new set of random points. You can optimize it further, but the code'd look similar to:

```
var possibleValues: [Point] = []
for x in 0..<5 {
    for y in 0..<5 {
        possibleValues.append(Point(x: x, y: y))
    }
}

func randomPoints(numberOfPoints: Int) -> [Point] {
    // shuffle original array without changing it
    let shuffled = possibleValues.sorted { _ in arc4random_uniform(10) > 5 }
    // take first X elements
    return Array(shuffled[0..<numberOfPoints])
}

randomPoints(numberOfPoints: 10)
```

You can optimize this solution even further but that'd require to know more about your data set. Hope this helps

Comment: I had written nearly identical code, so upvoted! :-)

Comment: var live = Array<Array<Int>>()

Comment: could you please update you code, in the current version there is also unknown `cells` array…